C#, ConfigurationBuilder и типизированные значения
я не понимаю, почему при стандартном чтении json-файла с конфигурацией параметры конфиграции приходят мне как строки, независимо от того, как они написаны в json-файле.
Поясню.
Вот я создаю стандартный консольный проект на NET Core 8, добавляю туда зависимости Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration и Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json
Затем прямов Main'е я пишу
    var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder().AddJsonFile("appSettings.json", false, false);
    var configuration = builder.Build();

    var rc = configuration["retryCounter"];

Затем я добавляю  appSettings.json, в котором написано
{
    "retryCounter": 42
}

... и в коде я получаю строку со значением "42":

И вот чего я не понимаю:

json у нас - типизированный. Да, там есть только примитивные типы, но число
 "retryCounter": 42    



отличатеся от строки
    "retryCounter": "42"


Если я буду пользоваться своим классом, каким нибудь MySettings.cs с описанными в нём полями, и буду его сериализовать - десериализовать в json - то у меня будет преобразование в json и обратно, сохраняющее элементарные типы (int, string, float)

В то же время, использование конфигурации и ConfigurationBuilder'а - это рекомендуемый путь. То есть, если ты делаешь не так - то тебе в приличном месте дадут по рукам.


Так почему же тогда этот рекомендуемый путь - такой ограниченный, и не отличается от работы с ini- файлом? Здесь есть какой то смысл, которого я не понимаю, или это просто "все данные в мире - это строки, и не надо нам морочить голову!"?

Чтобы полностью типизированно, нужно что-то такое использовать: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder/

Это лучше спросить у microsoft. Вот код этого парсера из репозитория dotnet, который преобразует любой элементарный тип в строку. Ссылка

Круто! Большое спасибо за объяснение и за совет по поводу Configuration.Binder! Не хотите оформить как ответ? Вообще, я немного подумал, и решил, что преобразование "всего в строку" - это чтобы абстрагироваться от источника конкретного параметра: ведь он может быть задан не только в json, но и в Environment, например

Я оставлю свой ответ со своими мыслями по поводу решения microsoft сделать именно так. Когда просмотрел реализацию - немного уложилось в голове их идея

@S.H. добавил свой ответ. Если нужно включить информацию по пакету, который выслал WhiteKnight - дайте знать. Я больше сфокусировался на ответах на ваши вопросы

Configuration in .NET - на мой взгляд, в документации всё достаточно хорошо описано. Чтобы получить типизированные значения вместо строк, используем методы Bind, Get, GetValue. Их список: IConfiguration Interface.

А так, да: все данные (вернее, конфиги) в мире - это строки. Их можно брать из файлов, БД, переменных окружения, из памяти и многих других источников.

Кратко
Причины такого подхода работы с конфигурацией (на мой взгляд):

Универсальность. В такую структуру данных можно поместить конфигурацию любого формата, нужно лишь правильно преобразовать изначальный формат в словарь.
Строгая типизация языка C# накладывает ограничения на хранение разнотипных данных в одном словаре. Придется либо в ущерб производительности использовать общий тип object для хранения значений, что приведет к boxing / unboxing значений конфигурации, либо придется изменить способ хранения данных, что может "ударить" по универсальности.


Подробнее
Внутри ConfigurationBuilder метод .Build() возвращает ConfigurationRoot, который в свою очередь использует доступные ConfigurationProvider для получения значений конфигурации.
ConfigurationProvider устроен таким образом, что данные конфигурации хранятся как словарь с параметрами "ключ-строка", или Dictionary<string, string?>
Поскольку C# - строго типизированный язык, то при желании хранить данные с нужной типизацией для элементарных типов придется воспользоваться Dictionary<string, object?>, и при вытаскивании данных передавать тип, который мы ожидаем на выходе (либо использовать dynamic). Выходит не очень практично, да и есть накладные расходы на boxing / unboxing. Ведь всем хочется получать конфигурацию максимально быстро и потребляя меньше памяти.
Также, ConfigurationProvider - базовый абстрактный класс, который переиспользуется в более конкретных реализациях. Идея хранить все значения как пара "ключ - строка" - вполне разумная для строго типизированного языка программирования. Мы получили строгую плоскую структуру данных, где доступ к универсальному строковому значению можно получить по композитному ключу (который напоминает ключи redis cache). Структура простая, и мы получаем общий интерфейс работы с конфигурацией, который можно применять при любых других способах получения конфигурации, не только JSON (например, из текстового файла, из БД и др.). В каком-нибудь Javascript, где типизация динамическая, хранить значения с оригинальным типом было бы уместно.
